# Dividends reinvestment in my Fidelity 401K

Tags: dividends

Why do my stock dividends have to be reinvested in my Fidelity 401k account? I would like to invest them where I think the best opportunities are.

Comment: Are the stocks in question held in the same 401k account?

Comment: Yes I would like for them to go into my Brokerage account.

Comment: Is the Brokerage account in the same 401k account?

Comment: Yes it is the same account.

Comment: Possibly related: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/78407/dividends-why-the-push-to-reinvest

Comment: I understand the Pro's of money being reinvested for no fees. Just wondering if any one knows why I can't chose not to reinvest and hold the cash until I decide where to put it to work.

Answer (score 6):

Dividends from a 401k investment (a tax-deferred vehicle) are themselves considered earnings.  Thus, they must remain in the same tax-deferred status.  You **cannot** transfer 401k dividend earnings to a **non-qualified plan** without paying income tax (ordinary, not the lower qualified dividend rate) and possibly a 10% penalty (if you are under 59 1/2 years of age).

You **may** be able to do a rollover into a different tax-deferred vehicle such as an IRA or a different employer's 401k, though this is unlikely and would depend heavily on the circumstances and the plan rules.

Depending on your particular 401k plan, you may have a self-directed investment option, in which case you can use those dividends as you wish (including leaving them as cash for a time) but the major point is that the funds must remain in the same account to retain the tax-advantaged status.

Answer (score 1):

By default capital gains and dividends are reinvested at Fidelity.  However, they can be changed, and if I recall correctly, you can reinvest one and not the other if you wish.

[See this page, login, and select your preferences.](https://www.fidelity.com/customer-service/how-to-dividend-and-cap-gains-distributions)

Since this will direct you to a Fidelity login page, for extra safety google:

"how to not reinvest dividends fidelity" and click on the link that says:

> How to Change Dividends and Capital Gains Distributions - Fidelity